# Extracting and storing characters from String

Tags: java, string, char

I want to write a program that reads an English word and stores it in "char" form like this:

"Apple" --> "A", "p", "p", "l", "e"

How can I do this?

Comment: Missing "homework" tag here? Also you may want to read this: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Using which programming language? Also, you should be more specific on where the program would read the word from, and where it would store the result.

Comment: You could start with downloading JDK and reading some tutorial on String operations

Comment: I'm sorry about that @Guffa. I've just added a tag of "java" to it.

Comment: It's actually not a homework @ivantod. It's only my personal curiosity to know how to work out this in java programming. Perhaps you've read my profile about being a secondary student and studying in a course and so you might think that this question is just for helping myself finishing homework. But this isn't the fact here. So please don't misunderstand. Furthermore, I really appreciate that you have posted a link about smart questions to my post. But I have to state that asking smartly or not is not the focus here, instead helping others to solve their questions is the main focus.

Comment: @benjchang  I disagree. If you go to this site's help page: (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you will find at the bottom the very same link I posted in my comment to you. Why should anybody invest any effort to help you if you haven't invested any effort to try and solve the problem on your own first? Especially with something like this which could have been solved by simply opening the javadoc page for `String`?

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "Apple";
char letters[] = a.toCharArray();
```